# PHP passing mysql query result to be displayed on another page

Tags: php, mysql

Apologies if this is an amateur question, my PHP skills are still in development. I've currently created a search box with the current code.

```
<?php    
        // Tyre search setup
        $profileSql = "SELECT DISTINCT `profile` FROM `tyres` WHERE `profile` > 0 ORDER BY `profile`";
        $profileResult = $db->query($profileSql);

        $widthSql = "SELECT DISTINCT `width` FROM `tyres` WHERE `width` > 0 ORDER BY `width`";
        $widthResult = $db->query($widthSql);

        $diamSql = "SELECT DISTINCT `diam` FROM `tyres` WHERE `diam` > 0 ORDER BY `diam`";
        $diamResult = $db->query($diamSql);

        if(isset($_GET['profile']) && isset($_GET['width']) && isset($_GET['diam'])) {
            $profile = $_GET['profile'];
            $width = $_GET['width'];
            $diam = $_GET['diam'];

            $tyreSql = "SELECT * FROM `tyres` WHERE `profile` = " . $profile . " AND `width` = " . $width . " AND  `diam` = " . $diam . " AND rrp > 0 ORDER BY `profile`";
            $tyreResult = $db->query($tyreSql);
        }   
?>
```

Here is the form this logic is tied to.

```
<form id="formTyreSearch" name="tyreSearch" method="GET">
    <h2>Tyre Search</h2>
    <p>Use our search below to find the tyre for your car.</p>
        <div class="form-group">Tyre Profile:
            <select name = "diamSearch">
                <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($profileResult)) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['profile']; ?>"><?php echo $row['profile']; ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </select>
            </div>

       <div class="form-group">Tyre Width:
           <select name = "pcdSearch">
               <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($widthResult)) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['width']; ?>"><?php echo $row['width']; ?></option>
               <?php endwhile; ?>
            </select>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">Tyre Diam:
           <select name = "pcdSearch">
               <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($diamResult)) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['diam']; ?>"><?php echo $row['diam']; ?></option>
               <?php endwhile; ?>
          </select>
      </div>

        <button type="submit" name="filterOptions" value="displayManu" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Search Now</button>
</form>
```

Now from here I assume the values selected in the form are set in the $tyreResult variable.

I want to pass this result to a tyres.php page and display the search result there, what is best practice to do this? and how should I handle if the user hasn't selected all three values, as there is going to be other content on the site I don't really want to reload the page and display an error at the top...

Comment: I suggest converting your result to JSON and use POST to send the data to the other page. You don't need a form. Just get the JSON and convert again in your result object.  Check this http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php to learn how to manage JSON data in PHP. Then check this http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php for curl to POST the JSON data to the other PHP page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an `action` attribute to your form and move the result logic into `tyres.php`. If they haven't selected all values, redirect them back to the previous page. But that shouldn't happen unless the user mischievously alters your HTML. By default, the first options of your `<select>` tags will be selected.

**search.php**

```
<?php    
// Tyre search setup
$profileSql = "SELECT DISTINCT `profile` FROM `tyres` WHERE `profile` > 0 ORDER BY `profile`";
$profileResult = $db->query($profileSql);

$widthSql = "SELECT DISTINCT `width` FROM `tyres` WHERE `width` > 0 ORDER BY `width`";
$widthResult = $db->query($widthSql);

$diamSql = "SELECT DISTINCT `diam` FROM `tyres` WHERE `diam` > 0 ORDER BY `diam`";
$diamResult = $db->query($diamSql);
?>

<form id="formTyreSearch" method="get" action="tyres.php">
    <h2>Tyre Search</h2>
    <p>Use our search below to find the tyre for your car.</p>
    <div class="form-group">
        Tyre Profile:
        <select name="profile">
            <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($profileResult)) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['profile'] ?>"><?php echo $row['profile'] ?></option>
            <?php endwhile ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        Tyre Width:
        <select name="width">
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($widthResult)) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['width'] ?>"><?php echo $row['width'] ?></option>
        <?php endwhile ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        Tyre Diam:
        <select name="diam">
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($diamResult)) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['diam'] ?>"><?php echo $row['diam'] ?></option>
        <?php endwhile ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="filterOptions" value="displayManu" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-primary">
      <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Search Now
    </button>
</form>
```

**tyres.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['profile'], $_GET['width'], $_GET['diam'])) {
    $profile = $_GET['profile'];
    $width = $_GET['width'];
    $diam = $_GET['diam'];

    $tyreSql = "SELECT * FROM `tyres` WHERE `profile` = " . $profile . " AND `width` = " . $width . " AND  `diam` = " . $diam . " AND rrp > 0 ORDER BY `profile`";
    $tyreResult = $db->query($tyreSql);
} else {
    header('Location: search.php');
    exit;
}
?>

<!-- show the results -->
```

Comment: Hey Mikey, doesn't seem to pass through the values, just has tyres.php?tyreSearch= in the header. Also cant use the header('Location: ') as I get this error Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at includes\quickModalTyres.inc.php:127) in \tyres.php on line 55, 55 being the header, line 127 being <?php echo ob_get_clean(); ?>

Comment: That's weird. I would expect `tyres.php?pcdSearch=` based off your original code. You need to give unique names to your `<select>` tags as shown in my revised HTML code. In terms of that warning, it is because you started output buffering earlier in your code. Look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/1022914) for more information on how to fix this warning.

Comment: Hey Mikey, Thanks I had another look and changed it, I may end up editing it at a later date to use cases, so any one of the parameters can be used independently, but that's for another day. I'll have a look into that post, the modal has been giving me issues for awhile now (its where that ob_get_clean is called.